Iterate through rows, If Columnx=1 assign 1 in new column, after 10x times assign 2 in new column
I am a Rstudio/R novice and want to use R to create blocks in my data frame. I want the first 10 times the colour blue occurs in the data frame to have a number 1 assigned in a new column. Once number 1 has been assigned 10 times, the a 2 should be be entered into the new column in case a row contains Color= blue. I was thinking of iterating through the rows somehow but am not sure how to do it. The dataframe would look like this:
           Day Color Color_block 
13          01  Green   NA               
14          01  Green   NA                 
15          01  Blue    1             
16          01  Red     NA                 
17          01  Red     NA               
18          01  Blue    2 # Say that that the Color = Blue above in row 15 was the 10th time number 1 was assigned 

I feel like this cannot be that hard and I tried a little myself without success. maybe there is a very simple solution that I don't see. Thanks in advance!!
I tried using vectors for this but find it very difficult to get behind their logic. I started trying to build a function, which worked but seems very longwinded for what is is supposed to achieve.

You haven't really provided enough data to test on, but I think this should work:
library(dplyr) 
your_data |>
  mutate(
    color_block = ((row_number() - 1) %/% 10) + 1,
    .by = Color
  )


Hey thanks. Do you mind explaining how it works briefly?

x %/% 10 gives how many times 10 goes into the answer (integer division with no remainder. Essentially the same as floor(x / 10)). Try 0:13 %/% 4 for a simple example. So, we take the row number, subtract 1 so it starts and 0, and then %/% 10 which will give 10 0s, then 10 1s, then ten 2s, etc. until all the rows are labeled. Then we add 1 because you want to start at 1, not 0. And we do that "by group" defined by the Color column.
